# A tidy way of bundling checking for allocation failures and returning errors if so

Tags: c++

I'm working in C++ but its on Brew which doesn't support exceptions.

There's going to be lots of code of the form:

```
X* x = new X;
if (!x)
    return NoMemoryErrorCode;
```

Is there a nice elegant way of condensing the above 3 lines into one?  Something along the lines of:

```
X* x = ReturnIfNoMemory(new X);
```

I could do that with a #define but would prefer not to use the pre-processor.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you prefer to not use the preprocessor? It was intended to support cases like this.

Comment: What would be the best way of defining a define to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As return only returns from the current function to its caller, you cannot really shorten this code without the preprocessor.

E.g:

```
#define newOrReturn(x, t) t * x = new t; if (!x) return NoMemoryErrorCode

newOrReturn(x, int);
```

Comment: That's what I suspected but wanted to confirm. What's the best way of doing that?

Comment: E.g. `#define donew(x, t) t * x = new t; if (!x) return NoMemoryErrorCode`

Answer (score 0):

You could define a template function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <new>

using namespace std;

template <class myType>
myType* SafeNew()
{
    myType* ptr = NULL;
    try
    {
        ptr = new myType();
    }
    catch(bad_alloc& ba)
    {
        cerr << "Unable to allocate memory." << endl;
        throw NoMemoryErrorCode;
    }

    return ptr;
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
MyClass* cls = SafeNew<MyClass>();
```